# Eliminate GCD resource contention for SKTexture creation

Tags: cocoa, sprite-kit, uikit, grand-central-dispatch, cifilter

I am working on a SpriteKit, networking game, for four players.  I have to use GCD dispatch queues because I am using a sole collection of image resources in a Game.xcassets bundle and if I don't use GCD the networking get's blocked and stalls and crashes the game.  GCD queues makes this a non-problem, except a different problem I am having is this:

Let's say I create a game with four players and they all connect to the one who is chosen to be the server.  The creation of the complicated SKTextures and animation frames takes about 10 seconds on an iPad 2, and on an iPad Pro 12" it's about 2-3 seconds.

If they are all using a similar character that uses the same group of ASSETS, I have to load one character, and let GCD finish him off, then load player 2's character, and let GCD finish, then load player 3's and then 4's, all the while waiting for GCD to completely finish the building of the SKTextures and animation frames for each character before continuing to the next.

The reason I can't just say "Everybody, here are all the characters you need to make go off and create them, is because the CIFilters throws a BAD_EXEC because some other character is usually using one of the images that some character wants to also use, i.e. RESOURCE CONTENTION, (for images in the resource bundle? damn!)

My questions are:

Is there any way to flag the resources as readonly used freely by many?  or issue some kind of "copy" when I use the CIFilters, so that the resource is released for someone else to use them?

The only silly way to correct this and make GCD kick into overdrive, is to create a set of image resources for each player's creation time.

```
// So "guy_rightArm_step0.png" becomes:

guy0_rightArm_step0.png
guy1_rightArm_step0.png
guy2_rightArm_step0.png
guy3_rightArm_step0.png
guy4_rightArm_step0.png
```

and have them in the right spots in the Game.xcassets (their own for each player if need be) i.e. I have to create five batches of image resources (because there is a server only option, for 4 other players).

This way when I issue forth the Server MSGs that say build p1's char, p2's char, p3's char, p4's char, GCD uses the group of images stored locally for each character to manipulate on each other clients device.

Sounds crazy to me but this is the only way to get no resource contention and to have character creation without CIFilter image crashes.

Comment: oh and yes those are all identical images stored on each device just with different names.  So GCD won't fight over them during CIFiltering...

Comment: well I added the extra images and that didn't solve anything really at least on the iPad 2, that thing crashes like crazy, unless I give it time to run it's courses...

Comment: The reason your app is crashing is because you are using up all the memory doing your image processing. There is no "contention" in using the same input image, just don't write your code that consume all the memory. Put autorelease blocks around loops and make sure you cleanup resources before attempting weird workarounds.

Comment: Thanks, it's totally true, I have been going around how little (512MB) the iPad 2 RAM is, and the image processing is on 6-7 images 3 times for animation frames.